# Laravel View Cache location

Tags: cache, redis, laravel

Sorry if this seems trivial, but I need to be sure:

Where does Laravel 6 store the view cache? On the cache server or in the storage folder?

Does it get stored in my redis if I set it as the cache server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The view cache is always stored via the filesystem in `storage/framework/views`.

You can verify this by setting your cache to something like Redis, doing `php artisan view:clear`, and observing that folder after visiting a couple Blade views in the browser. Files will show up even when you're not using the file-based driver.

If you're on a multi-server load balanced setup, be aware this means you'll need to clear the view cache on *each* server independently. (Probably as part of your deployment process.)

Comment: Thanks Mate! How about if I create a fileserver with a shared storage folder, so the two or more webservers will have the exact same content in the storage folder?

Comment: @ImreBertalan I think that'd be adding needless complexity and a big single-point-of-failure. There's no real downside to the filesystem cache for views - it's going to be faster than any of the other cache drivers, and clearing it on deployment is easily automated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you set Redis as your cache server, then the view cache will be stored in Redis. The view cache will be stored in the storage/framework/views folder if you are not using Redis.